My c code is giving unknown segmentation fault
So I am doing the CS50 practice problem of week 4. It's about recovering a JPEG file that has been deleted so you enter the file check for 4 headers (first 3 the same and the 4th can vary but they gave you a solution) but the program is giving me a segmentation fault and I spend so much time debugging but still can't figure it out. I'm new and any help is appreciated
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //check for 2 command-line arguments
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Input one command-line argument\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    //the first 4 bytes which are the headers
    BYTE b[4];
    int filecounter = 0;

    //a line to check that I'm still not at the end of the file
    while (fread(&b, sizeof(b), sizeof(b), f) == sizeof(b))
    {
        if (b[0] == 0xff && b[1] == 0xd8 && b[2] == 0xff && (b[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            filecounter++;

            char filename[10];
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", filecounter);

            FILE *img = fopen(filename, "w");

            BYTE BLOCK[512];

            //Same checking for end of File
            if (fread(&BLOCK, sizeof(BLOCK), sizeof(BLOCK), f) != sizeof(BLOCK))
            {
                fclose(img);
                fclose(f);
                return 1;
            }

            fwrite(&BLOCK, 512, 512, img);
            fclose(img);
        }
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}


I tried debugging on multiple lines of code but ended up having to remove most of the program for it to stop giving segmentation fault so I couldn't really check where the error is.

Welcome! But please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned. All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow. This includes "asking" the question to an AI generator then copy-pasting its output as well as using an AI generator to "reword" your answers.

Big mistake, asking ChatGPT for code. a) it's usually flawed in some way, b) you learn nothing.

@WeatherVane no I took very little from it since I realized how flawed it is but it still opened my eyes on some minor issues. Thanks for the info !

Open the files in binary mode. Even when not strictly necessary it shows intent. Start with the output file set to NULL. Read 512 bytes at a time, don't read 4 and throw it away then read 512 more. Check what was read to see if it is the start of a new file. If it is then close the current file if it is open (not NULL), open the next file, and unconditionally write that block the the open file.

You've edited out the reference, but here it told you to read just 4 bytes of header at first, but you have not repositioned the file pointer.

Assuming that sizeof(BYTE) == 1, then fread(&b, sizeof(b), sizeof(b), f) will read 4 * 4 (16) bytes into your 4-byte array. That won't work very well. Either use 1 as the element size and 4 as the number of elements to read, or use 4 as the element size and 1 as the number of elements (I recommend the last one).

In MSVC it is necessary to open in binary mode. And fread(&BLOCK, sizeof(BLOCK), sizeof(BLOCK), f) is also incorrect: that's 262144 bytes.

@RetiredNinja I did most of what you said but I don't understand the last phrase. You say to check if it is the start of a new file but the 512-bit blocks are all inside one file and they are all next to each other. I read in binary and set the output file to NULL and I read 512 at a time but the error is still there.

Please read a bit more about fopen and its modes, as well as fread.

I don't know what you changed so I can't really comment on that. The file is constructed as 512 byte blocks. When you read a block it will either be a header block or not. If it is a header block you close the current file, increment the counter, open the new file. In either case you always write that block the the output file. I know you probably want to work it out on your own, because that's learning, but you can find a ton of working examples here and on https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ if you search.

Oh by the way, passing &b to fread is also wrong. It will work but is really the wrong type. You're supposed to pass a pointer to the first element of the array, but you pass a pointer to the whole array. The type of &b is BYTE (*)[4], not the BYTE * that is expected. You get the right type by just using plain b, as it decay to a pointer to its first element (i.e. b is the same as &b[0]).

@Someprogrammerdude tried it the segmentation error is fixed THANKS. But now I have an error of not copying correctly. Guess that's on me to fix. Thank you for the help.

@RetiredNinja yes, but there could be a catch: the 'broken' data might not begin with a header block, so the block should only be written if an output file is open.

@Someprogrammerdude I will try to read more about that certainly. They really throw problems with a lack of explanation (or I'm just dumb)

@WeatherVane The first block of the file is a header block. The output file will always be open if the logic is correct. You're correct though, it would be more resilient to not assume that.

@RetiredNinja I'm sure I have seen versions of this problem where the first block is not a header block.

@Someprogrammerdude: The first parameter of fread is void * restrict, not BYTE *. While passing b rather than &b would be conventional, the latter is not wrong in that it neither contravenes any rule of the C standard nor that the C standard’s specification of its behavior is any different than for b. Both will read bytes into the same locations, and there is no issue of aliasing that differs between them. It is just as valid to ask fread to read four bytes into four one-byte elements as it is to ask fread to read four bytes into one four-byte array.

@WeatherVane Fair enough. It wasn't when I did it, but I also had an if (out) fwrite(...) Anyway, the comments are pretty much pseudo-code and I figured they'd work out the real code on their own.

@RetiredNinja I edited the file can you please check for new problems? Sorry for the inconvenience.

@greec_d as I mentioned earlier, you've already read 4 bytes of the header block. Read the whole block, not just 4 bytes. Then decide whether it's a header block. And please don't keep posting code updates.

@greec_d No you're not dumb, just a beginner on your first steps learning.You will become less "dumb" as you get more experience. :-)

Take a close look at while (fread(b, 4, 1, f) == sizeof(b)). Are you reading the right number of bytes? You also want the fwrite for every block, not just the header block and you should only close the file before opening the next file.

@WeatherVane when I set b[512] and fread the size of b it gives a segmentation fault (this was my original issue)

You don't need b[]. Just read the whole block into your buffer. If it's a header block, close the file and open a new one. Then write the whole block. Uh, sorry, you've changed the code again. Please don't do that: SO isn't a "rolling code Q & A site".

@WeatherVane so upon looking closer at the problem I actually have to keep writing 512-bytes blocks until a new block with the said headers is found, then I have to open a new file and start again. Any idea what to change ?

I think that now, armed with new knowledge, you should take a break and rewrite the code. Then ask a new question if you have another problem.

Take a good look at fwrite(&b, 512, 512, img); too. If you're not sure what to use for the arguments or the correct order refer to fread and fwrite.

In addition look closely at the (currently posted) code. You open the file, write a block, and then immediately close it. Draw a flow chart.

@WeatherVane trying my best to create a loop to keep writing blocks until I find a new header. Thanks for the help !

You need to check that fopen succeeds too or else you may use a NULL pointer in the following operations.

I believe that segmentation fault source is in while (fread(&b, sizeof(b), sizeof(b), f) == sizeof(b)) you used & in the wrong place.
The function you should use is size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream).
It will get the reference of the variable as it do.

while (fread(&b, sizeof(b), sizeof(b), f) == sizeof(b))

you are trying to get into b (which is 4 bytes size) an amount of sizeof(b) (this number is 4) records of sizeof(b) size, or a total 16 bytes, in one shot.  Only if the file has exactly 4 bytes the fread() call will just read one record and will return 1 ---and not 4, which is again the expected number of records.
while (fread(&b, 1, sizeof(b), f) == sizeof(b))

would be a better approach, or even better, to consider each record 4 bytes long, so then:
while (fread(&b, sizeof(b), 1, f) == 1)

would stop only when a full record cannot be read, and you will get a complete record or nothing at all.
But using ..., sizeof(b), sizeof(b), ... is completely incorrect.
